# Scrolling till the end of long dynamic page with RSelenium

Tags: r, parsing, scroll, rselenium

I figured out how to scroll dynamic page with RSelenium, but the length of the page various each time so sometimes for long pages with many elements my code does not work and it stops before reaching the bottom of the page. Does somebody have any ideas how to avoid it? 
Thank you in advance!

My code example:
first one works very well it could be great to make it scroll this way till the end of the page. I somehow should define not the particular number of scrolls like there 10, but to assign the condition to repeat this kind of scrolls till the certain moment. But have no idea how...

```
    for(i in 1:10){ 
  cd$executeScript(paste("scroll(0,",i*10000,");"))
  Sys.sleep(3)    
}

###after 10 big scrolls starts mini scrolls like that###
element <- cd$findElement("css", "body")
flag <- TRUE
counter <- 0
n <- 5
while(flag){
  counter <- counter + 1
  #compare the pagesource every n(n=5) time, since sometimes one scroll down doesn't render new content
  for(i in 1:n){
    element$sendKeysToElement(list("key"="page_down"))
    Sys.sleep(2)
  }
  if(exists("pagesource")){
    if(pagesource == cd$getPageSource()[[1]]){
      flag <- FALSE
      writeLines(paste0("Scrolled down ",n*counter," times.\n"))
    } else {
      pagesource <- cd$getPageSource()[[1]]
    }
  } else {
    pagesource <- cd$getPageSource()[[1]]
  }
} #But unfortunately this line is also powerless before the real big pages so it stops before reaching the bottom
```

Comment: Instead of `page down` use `end`, `list(key = "end")`